# numerical series license mathematics

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

I am a student in the second year of a mathematics degree in computer science and I have encountered an exercise on numerical series.

The exercices tells us that : Let $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a real sequence verifying :
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{n} (a_i +1) = g; \quad 0<g\leq +\infty
$$
And the first question asks us to prove that $$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i +1)} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1-\frac{1}{g}\quad \text{ si } g \neq +\infty\\
1\quad \text{ si } g = +\infty
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: Well, i put down $\displaystyle S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(a_i +1)}$ I then added and subtracted 1 in the numerator and then calculated

Comment: we obtain $\displaystyle S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}(a_i+1)}- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(a_i+1)}$

Comment: Up to this point I can't conclude

Comment: It’s been long time I did problems of series. $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (a_i +1)} -\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^k (a_i+1)}$. Now show if $\lim…$ is finite then that sum $=1-\frac{1}{g}$ and if $\lim$ is infinite then sum $=1$.

Comment: that's my problem I don't know how I'm supposed to conclude with this stage. I did by iteration to have a simpler writing but ....

Comment: after iteration $$S_n = \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{0}(a_i+1)} - \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+1)}$$

Comment: Now it is the first term that is problematic